# Opera browser source button

Tags: opera

Is there a button to view raw source in opera browser?

The one from Vectronic's Opera Buttons

http://76.11.58.186/

gives rendered source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://operawiki.info/CustomButtons#webdev) you go! It's the document source button.

Hope this is what you were looking for!